# JavaFX FileChooser returning null even on file selection

Tags: file, javafx, null, filechooser

I've tried searching for a solution but haven't been able to find one online. So I'm assuming I'm the only with the problem and posting the code and the output too.

The dialog box shows up and on selecting a file, returns null instead of the file. I've tried brute force-ing this problem, but haven't been able to solve it.

package sample;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main extends Application {

    AlertBox alert = new AlertBox();
    File fileSelected;
    //FileChooser file = new FileChooser();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Java Code Generator");
        primaryStage.isAlwaysOnTop();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:C:\\Users\\Surya\\IdeaProjects\\UMLtoJava\\src\\sample\\codegen.png"));
        Label label = new Label("Please choose an option:");
        VBox layout2 = new VBox(25);
        HBox layout = new HBox(20);
        layout2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout2.getChildren().add(label);
        Button xml = new Button("Import XMI");
        Button close = new Button("Close");
        Label exc = new Label("Please select a file");
        Button trial = new Button("Trial");
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.getChildren().add(xml);
        layout.getChildren().add(close);
        //layout.getChildren().add(trial);
        layout2.getChildren().add(layout);
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter exts = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XMI files (*.xmi)", "*.xmi");
        FileChooser file = new FileChooser();
        file.getExtensionFilters().add(exts);
        xml.setOnAction(e -> {
            fileSelected = file.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            try {
                String name = file.getInitialFileName();
                System.out.println(name);
                App gen = new App();
                gen.app(fileSelected);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        trial.setOnAction(e -> {
            App abc = new App();
            try {
                File trialfile = new File("C:\\Users\\Surya\\Documents\\Java From UML\\XML UML\\trial.xmi");
                abc.app(trialfile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                boolean confirm = alert.alert("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to close?");
                if (confirm) {
                    primaryStage.close();
                }
            }
        });
        close.setOnAction(e -> {
            boolean confirm = alert.alert("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to close?");
            if (confirm) {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout2, 500, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


package sample;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    AlertBox alert = new AlertBox();
    Button validate;
    Button gen;
    Button xmlfile;
    String text;
    StringBuilder input;
    Scanner filein;
    public void app(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.setTitle("UML to Java Code Gen");
        window.setMaximized(true);
        window.getIcons().add(new Image("file:C:\\Users\\Surya\\IdeaProjects\\UMLtoJava\\src\\sample\\codegen.png"));
        Scene scene;
        VBox layout = new VBox(100);
        HBox inlayout = new HBox(20);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        inlayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        validate = new Button("Validate XMI");
        gen = new Button("Generate Code");
        gen.setDisable(true);
        xmlfile = new Button("Import XMI");
        inlayout.getChildren().addAll(validate, gen, xmlfile);
        Scanner filein = new Scanner(file);
        while(filein.hasNext()){
            text = filein.nextLine();
            input.append(text);
        }
        TextArea displayfile = new TextArea(input.toString());
        displayfile.setWrapText(true);
        displayfile.setPrefColumnCount(100);
        layout.getChildren().add(inlayout);
        layout.getChildren().add(displayfile);
        scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        window.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                boolean confirm = alert.alert("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to close?");
                if (confirm) {
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


null
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.App.app(App.java:44)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:56)
    at sample.Main$$Lambda$70/1220713843.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/597514034.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You get the `NullPointerException` simply because you never initialize `input`. And the output "null" is simply from `getInitialFileName` in the file chooser, which was never set; but you never use that anyway (so I'm not sure why you're outputting it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Initializing was the problem.